# Best way to save date into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to save date into database, and than, when I will be getting results from database, I want to order them by date and classify them by date: for example show results, which are less than one day old and so on... what is the best way to save date?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: What do you mean by "*Best way*"?

Comment: Using a date type? :)

Comment: What is the easiest way, how to save date and than order and classify it by old = "Best way"
How? I´m quite confused about it...

Comment: I used datetime format and save it this way, but how to show date in other format? I saved it like this: H:i:s y-m-d and I want to show it like this: d-m-y H:i

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're referring to the MySQL column data type, use `DATE` unless of course you want times included as well, in which case it's `DATETIME`. A common one was always `TIMESTAMP`, but different architectures could give unwanted results.

In summary: `DATE`

About date and time formats: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

As for ordering, it would be the same as normal: `ORDER BY my_date_column`

Less than 1 day old: `WHERE my_date_column = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: To allow an available index to be used, we need a bare column reference in the predicate., e.g. for a date, datetime or timestamp column: `WHERE my_date_column >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 DAY AND my_date_column < DATE(NOW())`.  For a date column, this will also work: `WHERE my_date_column = DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -1 DAY`

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes, good point - hadn't thought of indexes. I've updated that query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `timestamp` as data type for the column where you store the date. To store the date, use the function `now()` if you wish to store the current time.

Or use the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) function in PHP:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('22-09-2008');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table create a field called "LastSaved" with the datatype of TIMESTAMP.  Then you can either in your query when saving or insert data update this field with NOW() as the value.

Or if you use triggers create a basic triggers in the Before Insert and Before Update events

```
SET NEW.LastSaved= NOW();
```

To order the results you can do something like

```
SELECT FieldName FROM YourTableName
ORDER BY LastSaved DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetime is a good solution,but if you care about daylight saving time use timestamp.